# Can I find a control by name and change a property in a single command?

Tags: c#, controls, findname

Can we find a control by name and change a property using a single command in C#?  I have this:

```
TextBlock tb = mainGrid.FindName("FirstNameTextBlock") as TextBlock;
tb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Is there a way to do it with a single command?  This doesn't work, but something like this:

```
(TextBlock)mainGrid.FindName("FirstNameTextBlock").Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is

```
((TextBlock)mainGrid.FindName("FirstNameTextBlock")).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

You need to cast the object and then modify the properties. The parentheses will take care of this. Without them it assumes whatever `FindName` returns has a property `Visibility` and that will be cast into `TextBlock`.

Comment: Note that this is trading NRE vs. InvalidCast exceptions - better be sure the control is there and of correct type.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, usually there is no point in saving one row when you should be checking the type anyway.